# swift init is unavailable. init not available can only be created by the framework internal

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to init instance of class (ObjC version) of internal framework:

```
MyClass *tmp = [Myclass New]; // <-- this works great
```

But I'm trying to something similar in swift:

```
var tmp = Myclass()
```

But in the swift case I'm getting this error:

swift init is unavailable. init not available can only be created by the framework internal

Why on ObjC don't get the error and why on Swift I'm getting this error?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Where is the class you are referring to stored?

Comment: you can do that with any class on ObjC. NSArray *array = [NSArray new]. In particular the class is an internal framework

Comment: What makes your framework "internal?"  Where is the Objective-C code creating a `MyClass` instance?  Is it in the framework?  In an application using the framework?  Somewhere else?  Same question about the Swift code trying to create an instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to access the object from swift for whatever reason. You could try to write a method that returns a new version of that object in objective-C and make it available to swift through a bridging header.

However any other methods that are private in objective-C won't be accessible in swift. So you might have wrap extra methods in objective-C and make them accessible to swift with other bridged objective-C methods.